# Access Denied para descargar virtualbox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

Intento bajar virtualbox y no me deja.

```
You don't have permission to access "http://download.virtualbox.org/errors/otnembargoed.html" on this server.
Reference #18.ffc3117.1661441293.25f1a588
```

Agradeceré su ayuda

Comment: download from the official page https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Desde qué país intentas descargar VirtualBox? Suena a restricciones comerciales relacionadas con políticas de EUA.

Comment: De Venezuela amigo

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! Saludos desde Colombia, vecino. Desafortunadamente, todo indica que Oracle está bloqueando la descarga debido a restricciones comerciales que impusieron los seres de allá al norte.

Incluso si recibieras el instalador por otro medio, la licencia de uso restringe el uso de los productos Oracle a los países en las listas OFAC de sanciones (y ahí tienen aún a Venezuela) porque no pueden hacer negocios con esos países ni exportar productos de ciertos tipos, incluyendo tecnología.

Trata de usar Xen, Qemu o Proxmox que son alternativas open-source y no vas a chocar con este tipo de restricciones...

Comment: Okey amigo. Muchas gracias por la aclaracion

Comment: O construir virtualbox desde los fuentes? https://github.com/mirror/vbox

Comment: @eftshift0 es claro que esos fuentes son MUY viejos?

Comment: ugh... no me fijé en ese detalle _insignificante_. :-D

Comment: @eftshift0 desde que Oracle compró eso, todo fue para peor jejeje. :(

Comment: @JesusMedina Acabo de mirar y el código fuente es accesible por svn (:-S) y el último commit es de ayer así que supongo que podrías hacer un checkout de ahí. https://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox

Comment: ... o hacer un clon con `git svn` ;-)

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus consejos!